# accessing form fields in html module in dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

in my dotnetnuke site, i have added a form and list module. And added the form containing fields name, occupation..., and records are added. will i able to get the values in another html module(row wise or column wise)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. What I understand is, you have listing of some object in one module and insert/update/delete in another module and you've installed both of them in same tab and now you wan to update listing module when edit module changes.

you can use [IMC](http://kemmis.info/blog/archive/2008/02/22/dotnetnuke-inter-module-communication-or-how-your-modules-can-get-their.aspx) for implementing such kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access the data from an HTML Module. But, you can certainly display the data in a variety of ways. If you want the same people who enter the data to view the data, just go into module settings and for "Appearance", select "Form Above List" or "Form Below List". That will cause the module to display both the Form and the List.

If you need more advanced control, you could also use the Reports module or a module like Efficion's Advanced Data Grid to display the data but you'll need to understand SQL pretty well to make those work.